New shower gurgles, is this normal or cause to bring the installer/plumber back?
I recently had an old fiberglass tub removed and a shower installed. We went from 1" (or something) drain to a 2" drain (or something) per the code. Now there's a gurgling noise in the drain that wasn't there w/the bathtub.
video - I turn the shower off around the 5 second mark:
removed
Is this common/expected for a shower drain?
You can also see, at the end of the video, it looks like there's some water that sits in the drain -- drops fall into it/ripples -- is this ok or should all the water flow out?

"there's some water that sits in the drain" - That's because you are looking straight down into the trap. If there wasn't water there, it would stink. Literally.

Everything looks normal, including the noise

It looks and sounds normal, although quite loud.   Maybe that's because the mic is so close.  But if the sound is annoyingly loud in person, and if you still have access to the underside, you might be able to reduce the resonance a bit by wrapping the tail piece and trap in some heavy material.  There's a purpose made material, MLV, that's very expensive, and all kinds of sound-deadening stuff made for automotive.  Maybe even a few wraps of heavy duck tape will do the trick.  It's a big maybe, I can't tell if the PVC is contributing to the resonance or it's just a lot of echo.

That's probably a normal sound.  If you want to make sure it's draining ok, either pour some 5 gallon buckets of water into your shower, or block the drain temporarily with the shower running to let the shower base fill with some water (making sure it doesn't overflow), and then when you remove the drain block, the water should flow smoothly and quickly into the drain.  It shouldn't start to flow then slow down once the drain piping gets full.  But that looks normal to me.

Your video shows a normal shower drain.
You are noticing a difference because the tub drain collected the water and ran it horizontally before dropping into the P-trap.

Thank you! Just wanted to know if it was something to 'worry' about or not.
